# Android Project generated using Worklight 6.1, is it regenerated for each compilation?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

In older Worklight version's, when a android project folder gets generated after adding native env. each time when the corresponding Worklight project is rebuilt any changes made to the native project (suffixed with Android)gets refreshed. Is it the same in Worklight 6.1 too ? In that case the native changes needed to be added each time a new version of the app is released. Please help/advice.

Answer (score 0):

The generated Android project is basically a mirror of the android\native folder.
When you choose Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server, your changes will then be present in the generated Android project.

This has been the case since day #1 and is still the case now.

Comment: So does deploying on the Worklight Server bring back the old code for the client side !!

Comment: If you make code changes in the **generated** Android project rathen than in the **Worklight** project and you then re-build the project before first copying over your changes, then yes - this will bring back the "previous client code". **Obviously**.